# Building a keras model to apply a Dense network to every column in a 3-D array and return a 2-D array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a large number of `n`x`m`x`m` arrays. I would like to train a keras model that learns a single Dense NN to apply to all of the `n`x`1` column vectors. As a concrete example, suppose `A` is a `6`x`10`x`10` tensor; it therefore has 100 `6`x`1` column vectors.

I have a keras model to train a Dense neural network:

```
import keras as K
import keras.layers as L

def column_nn():
   layers=[12,36,12,1]

   columns=L.Input(shape=(6,))
   x=L.Dense(layers[0],activation='relu')(columns)
   for l in layers[1:]:
       x=L.Dense(l,activation='relu')(x)
   return K.models.Model(inputs=columns, outputs=x)
```

I'd like to apply this to each of the 100 column vectors, but I want to return a 2-D `10`x`10` tensor that I can do other things to, such as pass through `Conv2D` layers.

One way that comes to mind is to use reshaping and a keras shared layer.

```
data=L.Input(shape=(6,10,10))
column_nn=column()
x=L.Permute((2,3,1))(data)
x=L.Reshape((-1,6))(x)
new_layer=column_nn()(x)
x=L.Reshape((10,10))(new_layer)
# now do a bunch of stuff to the 2-D new_layer, such as 
x=L.Conv2d(filters=5,kernel_size=[3,3])(x)
x=L.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2))(x)
x=L.Flatten(x)
output=L.Dense(x)
return K.models.Model(inputs=A,outputs=output)
```

Seem ok? I'd love to know if if there were a slicker way to pull this off?

Answer (score 1):

If you reshape and transpose your input data to `(m*m, n)`, you can use `Dense(k)` in conjunction with `TimeDistributed` to apply the same weights to the m^2 vectors separately. The output shape would be `(m*m, k)`, after which you can reshape again to suit your needs

Comment: I was just looking into reshape and transpose when you wrote this. :-)  Great pointer on using `TimeDistributed`.  I will definitely look into it.

Comment: This answer is ok, but `TimeDistributed(Dense(...))` is equal to just `Dense(...)`. -- The layer will be applied to the last dimension.